# How to embed pom descriptors in a jar

Tags: sbt

When a jar is created using Maven. The META-INF directory in the jar contains sub-directory maven/group-id/artifact-id with `pom.xml` and `pom.properties`. How to do it with SBT?

Is there an option of a plugin that does that?

Answer (score 3):

You can always publish 'maven style' with sbt - This will create the pom and pom.properties correctly.

To do this, you can use:

```
publishMavenStyle := true
```

And you will probably need to add the extra information required by the pom. To do this, set `pomExtra`:

```
pomExtra :=
<licenses>
  <license>
    <name>Apache 2</name>
    <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
    <distribution>repo</distribution>
  </license>
</licenses>
```

For more information, see the docs: [Publishing](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Publishing.html) and the following describes in detail how to publish to a maven repo: [Deploying to Sonatype](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Community/Using-Sonatype.html).

Comment: I do not have issue with publishing to a maven repo. A actually do have `publishMavenStyle`, `pomExtra` and other details needed to publish on Sonatype. I do not need to publish to a maven repo.

Comment: I need to package my binaries into a jar with mentioned directories in `META-INF`. That jar is used to distribute plugin for Fiji (http://fiji.sc). Description, developer, and other info is read from pom.xml inside jar by Fiji plugin manager to display the info to Fiji user.

I can repackage jar by hand (or Maven), just looking if there is a simple way to do it in SBT. Maven does it by default.